# How to override forced after hours shutdown Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008

My network admin shutsdown all computers on the network at 6pm, but I need my computer to remain on for the rest of the evening. Is it possible to override this after hour shutdown policy locally? I have admin rights on my computer.

Comment: I'd suggest talking to your network admin.

Comment: nope, not an option.

Comment: Your network admin probably has a reason for shutting down the computers, just like you have a reason to need yours left on. You should explain your requirement to your network administrator so that they can make accommodations for your requirement and at the same time be able to do their job and know whats going on within the network.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can prevent a restart or shutdown using the command

`shutdown /a` within the time-out period

Try running the above command in CMD with admin privileges and check

Answer (score 1):

It depend on how it done.

If it policy (I don't know about this way) or by local scheduler, local admin can change policy.

If it remote shutdown command and it issued for immediate shutdown. Hard to do somthing, except remove domain admins from local admins group.

If it remote shutdown with timeout. In this timeout other admin (local) can cancel shutdown process.

So, after each boot and login, local changes can be overwritten by domain and need to be restored in some way.